# ASP.NET Core API POST parameter is always null from Firefox

Tags: ajax, .net-core, angular2-services

In my `Angular2 Application`, I'm submitting a form and send data through `POST API to dotnet core backend`. I've created a new form, that is working fine with chrome, but on firefox, **I'm receiving null in POST API parameter**.

I'm all stuck what to search and how to?? I've checked every possible issue and didn't find anything, because App is working fine with chrome, all data is up to date and correct but **a single form is not working on firefox**.

> Can anyone help me out what to do? because I'm totally stuck and have
>   no idea what to do??

**My Endpoints are;**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Intimation/SaveIntimation")]
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveIntimation([FromBody] ViewModelCreateIntimation objCreateIntimation)
{
    if (objCreateIntimation == null || objCreateIntimation.objIntimation == null)
            {

                return Ok("null received");
            }
           // remaining code
}
```

**my service on angular side**

```
saveIntimation(intiModel) {
console.log(intiModel);
return this.httpClient.post<ViewModelResponse>(this.baseUrl + this._SubmitIntimationUrl, JSON.stringify(intiModel), { headers: this.configurations.getHeaderWithAuth() });
  }
```

where `this._SubmitIntimationUrl` is `"/api/Intimation/SaveIntimation"`, `intiModel` is object that I'm passing.

**Controller function - Angular**

```
this.intimationModel = this.admissionForm.value;
this.adminService.SubmitAdmissionIntimationService(this.createIntimationModel).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    this.responseModel = response;
    // further process
    },

  (error) => {

    this.notification.onClear();
    this.notification.onError(this.errorHandler.handleError(error).error, Constants.MESSAGE_ERROR);
  }
);
```

**Data that is sending from service (Last place where I can check data)**

[image: Intimation Data]

Comment: Please post the code of your form and the controller action.

Comment: that's a lot of code, should I post it all?

Comment: Yes please, otherwise it's really hard to say what's going on. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Use the developer tools in the two browsers. Compare the requests they are making. See what is different.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev I've added some code..

Comment: @Quentin I've checked it on both environment, only difference is in date object, otherwise all result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through same issue once, and It took almost a day to figure out the reason behind it,

do check your date pickers and its values, and make sure it is not null and its format is also correct. Because firefox is a bit strict in this matter and a litter change in datepicker makes it null.

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks like it's because of the name of the parameter in your controller is different to that being passed up in the request.

In your controller, the parameter the framework is trying to bind to is called `objCreateIntimation`, but your request shows you're sending up `objIntimation` instead. As they have different names, the model binder has no idea that `objIntimation` should be bound to `objCreateIntimation`.

Give them both the same name, and that should fix it for you.

Comment: I've tried to change these names as well. but no difference. Point is *it is working fine with this on chrome*

Comment: @NullPointer If you've tried changing them, perhaps the reason is local caching of scripts with the wrong names. Flush your browser cache.

Comment: @NullPointer Ok, make sure the names are the same, as that is definitely a requirement. After that, it would probably be worth examining the headers being sent in each request, as Firefox is a lot more strict than Chrome in many areas.